# Improve Prim's algorithm runtime

Tags: prims-algorithm

**Assume we run Prim’s algorithm when we know all the weights are
integers in the range {1, ...W} for W, which is logarithmic in |V|.  Can you improve Prim’s running time?**

When saying 'Improving', it means to at-least:
$$O(|E|)$$

My question is - without using priority queue, is it even possible?
Currently, we learned that Prim's runtime is $$O(|E|log|E|)$$

And I proved I can get to O(|E|) when weights are from {1,....,W) when W is constant, but when W is logarithmic in |V|, I can't manage to disprove/prove it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you credit the source where you encountered this task?  How quickly can you sort all of the weights?

Comment: @D.W. A University task. sorting is O(nlogn).
How can we prove that something can't run in better time?

Comment: Think about all sorting methods you know.  Are there any linear-time sorting algorithms that work under any conditions?